# Replace a null value with string in multple field

Tags: powershell, active-directory

how can I replace a $null value in the `Lastlogon` field by a string "never log" and also place this value in the column "Last Logon days"

```
Search-ADAccount -UsersOnly  -AccountDisabled:$false | Get-ADUser -Properties Name, LastLogon | select Name, @{N='LastLogon'; E={[DateTime]::FromFileTime($_.LastLogon)}}, @{N='Last Logon Days'; E={$($(Get-Date) - $([DateTime]::FromFileTime($_.LastLogon))).Days}}
```

I have accounts that never logged on the network and they are returning a last logon date of 12/31/1600 7:00:00 PM  which is a bite far away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this as your select statement:

```
select Name, @{N='LastLogon'; E={`
    if ( [DateTime]::FromFileTime($_.LastLogon) -eq $null ) {
        return "Never log" }
    else { return [DateTime]::FromFileTime($_.LastLogon) }}},`
    @{N='Last Logon Days'; E={`
    if ( [DateTime]::FromFileTime($_.LastLogon) -eq $null ) {
        return "Never log" }
    else {  return $($(Get-Date) - $([DateTime]::FromFileTime($_.LastLogon))).Days}}}
```

I can't test this right now, but I have done similar things in the past with success.

Comment: Thanks @Nick it worked, I had to change the $null value bye the value "12/31/1600 7:00:00 PM" because the field wasn't empty. But your command worked just perfectly